# Update AssemblyInfo const variable

Tags: build, constants, task, pipeline, assemblyinfo

I have a single file where I specify my version:

[image: assemblyfile]

I try to update it with the 'Update AssemblyInfo' task on build pipeline:

[image: build task]

when executing the task do logs the update:

```
Searching for files...


============================================================

D:\BuildAgent01\_work\21\s\AutomationGeneral\Properties\SharedAssemblyInfo.cs

Updating attributes
-------------------
Skipped 'AssemblyProduct' (no value defined)
Updating 'AssemblyVersion'...
Updating 'AssemblyFileVersion'...
Updating 'AssemblyInformationalVersion'...
Saving changes...
```

But the content of the file is not updated: it stills remains:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion(SolutionItem.Version)]
```

Do I need to remove the const string and put the string content inside of the parameter of the method?

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.1.1")]
```

so the replacement will be really done?

is not the Task messing here? or is it me?

Comment: please never add images of your code, add the code in reproducible way in textual form (paste and use formatting).

Comment: I do not see any edit button for the question ....

Comment: use [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64927133/edit) under the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it seems that once there is no more variable inside the parenthesis it works:
it manages to update only if there is string content in the parenthesis.

and when it succeeds it prints the version number too:

```
Configuration: 

Version: 1.20.1120.05

File version: 1.20.1120.05

InformationalVersion: 1.20.1120.05

Custom attributes:
```

Comment: dont you miss something after custom attributes?